# how to paginate an XML File

Tags: xml, pagination

I have been searching high and low for a way to paginate an XML file and i am beginning to think it might not be possible.. could anyone shed some light on this, is it possible, i can paginate database results no issue but can't find a way to do it...

Seen some examples but they used an ID field that was in the XML file, and as i can't edit the file myself, just gotta work with what i've got...

Hope someone can help...

Comment: Paginate an XML file? How do you mean paginate it? In a browser? Split it into files? Printing?

Comment: Sorry should have said more, i want to paginate a xml page using PHP, would have around 200 items (nothing massive)

Comment: The programming language doesn't matter. Define “paginate.”

Comment: Well i understand pagination to be the process of splitting up a list of data into pages that the user can navigate to through a simple navigation....

Comment: once upon a time there were these things called 'books' written on 'pages' made of 'paper'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XML has no concept of pages, because it's not a UI technology.

You certainly can.  You'd have to parse the XML into a DOM object, pick a page size, then iterate through the DOM in page-sized chunks.

You don't say which language you're using or whether you want server or client side.  But it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention how you render your XML in the first place, but you might want to take a look at e.g. [XSL-FO](http://www.w3schools.com/xslfo/default.asp), which supports paging.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file("your.xml")) {

trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);}


$ps = 16; // page size

$fr = $_GET["fr"];

if ($fr < 1) {

    $fr = 1;

}

$c = 0;

foreach($xml->product as $product) { // ->entry

    $c++;

    if ($c >= $fr && $c < $fr + $ps) {
        echo $c. '<b>Find out more about:<br><a href=\'http://www.shop-
diamondtdesign.com/p/product/'.$product->SUPPLIERITEMGUID.'\'>'.$product-
>ITEMNAME.'</a></b></br>'."\n";
        echo '<img 
src="http://www.distributorcentral.com/resources/productimage.cfm?
Prod='.$product->SUPPLIERITEMGUID.'&size=medium" alt="'.$product->ITEMNAME.'" /><br>';
        echo "Action - "    .($product->ITEMACTION)."<br>";
        echo "ADDED TO SEARCH DATE - ".($product->ADDEDTOSEARCHDATE)."<br>
</div>";

    }
}
    echo '<div class="w3-row ">';
    echo '<div class="w3-button w3-theme w3-round-large">';
if ($fr > 1) {
    echo "  &nbsp; &nbsp;  <b><a href='index.php?fr=" . ($fr - $ps) . "'>prev</a>";

} else {

    echo "  &nbsp; &nbsp;  <b><strike>prev</strike>";
}

// TODO: check end of file...

   echo " &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='index.php?fr=" . ($fr + $ps) . "'>next</a></b>";
echo "</div></div>";       
?>
<a href="paging-3.php" button class="w3-button w3-block w3-theme-l4 w3-hover-w3-theme-l2 w3-border-black">More Newest Additions</a>
```